# Django Query to Check if 2 records have the same set of related records

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

For each Message, I need to generate a query that annotates whether or not there are a conflicts with the annotations. Annotations are conflicting for a message if they don't all have the same text, urgency, and label_set. Note that for label_set I am not looking for the Annotations to reference the exact same objects. I am looking for each annotation to have a set of labels with the same names and topics (e.g. all annotations need 2 labels. One with name = 'A' and topic_id = 5, and one with name = 'B' and topic_id = 7). There can be an arbitrary number of annotations per message and an arbitrary number of labels per annotation.

```
class Message(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField()

class Annotation(models.Model):
    message = models.ForeignKey(to=Message)
    user = models.ForeignKey(to=User)
    text = models.CharField()
    reviewed = models.BooleanField()
    urgency = models.ForeignKey(to=Urgency)

class Label(models.Model):
   annotation = models.ForeignKey(to=Message)
   topic = models.ForeignKey(to=Topic)
   name = models.CharField()
```

Here is what I have so far. Note that there are other checks for unrelated things in the Case statement hence why I am using strings for the annotation value and not just a boolean for conflict/no conflict.

```
messages = Messages.objects.filter([arbitrary filter]).annotate(
    status = Case(
        When(GreaterThan(
                Count('annotation__urgency', filter=Q(annotation__reviewed=True),
                    distinct=True), Value(1)) | 
            GreaterThan(
                Count('annotation__text', filter=Q(annotation__reviewed=True),
                    distinct=True), Value(1)),
             then=Value('Conflict')
            ),
           default=Value('Multiple')
       )
```

However, I am not sure how to perform the checks for the labels. Does anyone know how to perform checks for the labels in here?

Comment: Is there a good reason to do this in SQL (and then to implement that in Django ORM calls)? I would simply read the relevant fields from the message's label_set and annotation_set, then analyze it in Python. Far easier to read. A good reason would be if that's intolerably inefficient, i.e. a large number of messages to process, but then you probably want an SQL expert to provide you with a raw SQL query.

Comment: @nigel222 this annotation is done in a custom filter because I allow filtering on this field. It is one of many filters that are allowed to be applied. The database has millions of messages so to be able to filter on it I either have to perform it in SQL or denormalize the database by pre-calculating the value in python whenever annotations and labels are modified. It’s unrealistic to pull in millions of messages.